# app apk Signing issue with Cordova-plugin-buildinfo

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Hybrid application is using a cordova-plugin-buildinfo plugin to read the version from config file , it is working fie in unsigned mode.For signed apk buildinfo plugin is not being picked hence app is throwing Class not found error.

Comment: So your issue is, the same code works when you build normal APK, but when you build release APK using Cordova command `cordova build --release android`, buildinfo plugin not found?

Comment: cordova build --release android command creates only android-release-unsigned.apk , this is not install-able in physical device. Android debug apk is working fine , issue with android signed release apk.